# Add JavaScript Function to Page Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which creates JavaScript code dynamically.

Now I want to add this function to the page so that this function can be executed on specific events using JavaScript or jQuery.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If your function assigns them to a variable you will be able to access them at any time.

So if your function essentially did:

```
var test = function() { 
   // ....
}
```

you could run that at any time by using test(). If you have multiple functions either assign them to an object or use an array.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `eval(string)` function, though it won't be advisable.